# Cycles Texture Painting on hair particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to paint over an existing texture with blender's texture paint in the cycles engine. When I paint my texture and then render the object the changes that I made to the texture are no longer there in the render.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In my current project, I'm trying to get rid of some discoloration on the model's scalp with Blender's texture painting.

Thanks!

[image]

I pushed F3 in the image editor to save and it gave me an error?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, could you please clarify? Edit your question and provide more details about what you want to achieve and why it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I made an edit, I hope it made things more understandable.

Comment: Not fluent in texture paint myself, but you may need to save your painted texture first, then use it in a material

Comment: Thank you for your response! I pushed F3 in the image editor to save, and it gave me an error?